# Add entity which contains composite Primary Key

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008-r2, entity-framework-5

I'm using Entity Framework (V5 I think) and am currently attempting to add a new row into a table.  The table I wish to add into has a composite primary key based on the value "PRN" (basically a unique customer ID) and an associated sequence number.  Each time the information in this table is updated we insert a new row for the PRN and increment the sequence number.  The sequence number is not defined as an automated incrementing value or IDENTITY on the database as it isn't unique - the sequence number is only unique per PRN.

When I execute the following code, I get an InvalidOperationException: "The property 'DDIPhasedPayment_Seq_Num' is part of the object's key information and cannot be modified."

EF doesn't seem to mind if I modify the PRN part of the Primary Key only and save the record (which results in a default value of zero for the Seq_Num) but throws the exception when I try to modify the other part of the PK.  How can I create and add a row to this table without upsetting EF?

```
var nextSequence = GetNextPhasedPaymentSequenceNumber(message.Prn);
var entity = new Practitioner_DDI_PhasedPayment()
{
    PRN = message.Prn,
    DDIPhasedPayment_Seq_Num = nextSequence,
    TSN = message.Tsn,
    //........
    //Various other fields populated
    //........
};
dbContext.Practitioner_DDI_PhasedPayment.Add(entity);

dbContext.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: Are you sure you're not changing a PK value in `GetNextPhasedPaymentSequenceNumber`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gert - thanks for your hint, that was exactly the problem:

```
private short GetNextPhasedPaymentSequenceNumber(int prn)
    {
        var lastPayment = WISERDb.Practitioner_DDI_PhasedPayment.Where(ddipp => ddipp.PRN == prn).OrderByDescending(k => k.DDIPhasedPayment_Seq_Num).FirstOrDefault();

        if (lastPayment == null) { return 1; }

        else { return ++lastPayment.DDIPhasedPayment_Seq_Num; }
    }
```

The use of the ++ operator here was the problem - it should have been returning the value + 1 instead.